# Filling an array of int array's parsed from a string array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to fill an array of int array's that are parsed from a string array.
I have tried this, and know that it's not right, but cant seem to figure out how to get it working.

```
String s[]{34 46 67 34, 95 02 00 34, 70 12 30 23, 01 13 54 91};

private static void gridMaker(String s){
    String[] temporaryString;
    int[] temporaryInt = new int[s.length()];
    int[][] grid;
    String[] splitString = s.substring(0, s.length()- 1).split("\\|");

    for(int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++){
       temporaryString = splitString[i].split(" "); 

        for(int n = 0; n < splitString.length; n++){
        temporaryInt[n] = Integer.parseInt(temporaryString[n]); 
        }
            grid[i] = temporaryInt;
     }

}
```

I figured it out. I didn't initialize grid with a length, and since the grid I am trying to create has an equal number of rows and columns, this works.

```
int[][] grid = new int[s.length()][];
```

Comment: How is the string that you make into the array formatted? In other words, what is `s`?

Comment: I figured it out, I was working on it for like an hour, and then as soon as I posted it, the answer came to me!

Comment: I never initialized grid[][] with a size;

Comment: Then for other users with the same problem, please answer your own question with the solution and accept the answer. That way anyone who comes here with a similar problem can find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `grid`:

```
grid = new int[splitString.length][];
```